# Cuál es el problema en el siguiente código en ReportViewer en VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

Cuál es el problema en el siguiente código en ReportViewer en VB.NET?

```
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class RptPedidosPrv
    Dim sParam(4) As ReportParameter    ' Parámetros

    Private Sub RptPedidosPrv_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Rsl As Boolean
        Dim Txt As String
        Dim T() As String

        T = Split(vFrm, "|")
        Txt = "Tlf: " & TlfE & " RIF: " & RIFE
        RV.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
        RV.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reportes\RptPedidoPrv.rdlc"
        sParam(0) = New ReportParameter("Logotipo", "File:" & CurDir() & "\Tecnileca.png")
        sParam(1) = New ReportParameter("Empresa", NomE)
        sParam(2) = New ReportParameter("Tlf", Txt)
        sParam(3) = New ReportParameter("Dir", DirE)
        sParam(4) = New ReportParameter("Prov", T(1))
        Rsl = Conectar()
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Txt = "SELECT  p.NomPrv,pp.NroPed,pp.FchPed,pl.CNTPed,(cp.DesCom & '-' & cp.DetCom) AS Cpte FROM " _
            & "((ProveedoresPed pp LEFT JOIN Proveedores p ON (pp.CodPrv=p.CodPrv)) " _
            & "LEFT JOIN ProvPedLineas pl ON (pp.NroPed=pl.NroPed)) " _
            & "LEFT JOIN Componentes cp ON (pl.CodCom=cp.CodCom) WHERE pp.NroPed=" & T(0)
        da = (New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Txt, Conn))
        da.Fill(ds)
        Dim data1 As New ReportDataSource("PedProv", ds.Tables(0))
        RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(data1)
        RV.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = True
        RV.LocalReport.SetParameters(sParam)
        RV.RefreshReport()
        Conn.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Si elimino todo lo que tenga que ver con los parámetros funciona, si lo dejo como está da el error:

> "ReportProcessingException: La definición de este informe no es válida
>   o no la admite esta versión de Reporting Services. La definición del
>   informe puede que se haya creado con una versión posterior de
>   Reporting Services, o que contenga contenido que no tiene el formato
>   correcto o que no es válido según los esquemas de Reporting Services.
>   Detalles: La definición de informe tiene un espacio de nombres de
>   destino no válido
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition'
>   que no se puede actualizar."

¿Alguien sabrá a qué se debe esto?

Answer (score 1):

Analizando e investigando, aparentemente para VS 2017 hay que instalar el ReportViewer para cada aplicación. Claro está que hay que desinstalar primero el componente.
Sigo investigando para ver si hay una solución menos Microsoft (Todo complicado para los desarrolladores)

Comment: Buen hallazgo. Y pues... bienvenido a Microsoft :P Siempre hay un wizard de configuración esperando por ti